# prevent page from jumping down and up after load content .load() Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a page with two section where I load content `.load()` into `#container` by clicking on the titles.

```
<div id="dogs">[dogs]</div> 
<div id="cats">[cats]</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**My problem**

When the content loaded is too small,  the page jumps down and up,

```
$("#dogs").trigger("click");   //initial

$("#cats").click(){function(){
      $("#container").load("content.php?s=cats"); //after click

}}

$("#dogs").click(){function(){
      $("#container").load("content.php?s=dogs"); //after click


}}
```

how do I prevent from the page to jumps down and up after loading the content? I want it to keep steady.

As a fix I added a `<div style="height:600px"></div>` at the bottom of the page, but after scrolling there is plenty of room below, I dont like.

Comment: Can you define a constant width and height in css for the container or should the container be flexible?

Comment: the width doesnt vary afer the load event `width:480px` always, the height is set to auto, because I dont know how large would be the content loaded (plenty of posts in different numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this code snippet and see if it helps :

```
if (location.hash) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn" id="dogs">[dogs]</div> 
<div class="btn" id="cats">[cats]</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){ //When btn class is clicked
        var idValue = $(this).attr('id') //Get the id value of the clicked div
        $('#container').css({ //Prevent scrolling
            "height": "100%",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        });
        $("#container").load("content.php?s="+idValue, function(){
            //When container is loaded
            $('#container').css({ //Allow scrolling
                "height": "auto",
                "overflow": "visible"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I have not tested it, so let me know if you're having any problems.

EDIT: Perhaps you should use `body` instead of `#container` because now I'm assuming it's jumping once when you click the button.

Comment: Ok, when clicked you alter the ccs of the container to overflow:hidden, then after the data is loaded you return to the original css. It has totally sense since overflow hidden doesnt allow scroll movements. Let me test it to accept your answer. Thank you.